# Linked list in julia

Tags: julia

can anybody help me to understand next things please: 

1) Why do we need to make a new abstract class of a future struct, while making linked list?

2) Why there is an argument T?

3) What does this operator do <: (haven't found it in the book) ?

4) Can we write in the following way, instead of Example ?:

```
type LinkedList 
    name = Ptr{Uint8}
    next :: LinkedList
end
```

Example:

```
abstract type LinkedList{T} end

mutable struct Nil{T} <: LinkedList{T}
end

mutable struct Cons{T} <: LinkedList{T}
   head::T
   tail::LinkedList{T}
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: For (3), the manual describes `<:` in [Abstract-Types-1](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#Abstract-Types-1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You don't. You actually can define recursive structures like the one you posted just fine.  Well, sorta.  `name = Ptr{Uint8}` is not the correct syntax — instead you want `name::Ptr{UInt8}`.  Although, really, you probably really just want `name::String`.  Now you'll still run into trouble:

   ```
   julia> struct BrokenList
              name::String
              next::BrokenList
      end

   julia> BrokenList("first", BrokenList("last", #= uh, what goes here? =# ))
   ```

   You need *something* of type `BrokenList` to already exist… but in order to create one you need one!  So a simple "out" is to allow `next` to either be another node of the list or some placeholder for the last element. `nothing` (which is of type `Nothing`) is a simple option:

   ```
   julia> struct BetterList
              name::String
              next::Union{BetterList, Nothing}
          end

   julia> BetterList("first", BetterList("last", nothing))
   BetterList("first", BetterList("last", nothing))
   ```
2. That `T` isn't an argument; it's a [type parameter](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Parametric-Types-1). Of course, our `BetterList` could just as easily hold `Int`s instead of `String`s… so we can use a type parameter to dynamically parameterize the type based upon the values it holds:

   ```
   julia> struct LinkedList{T}
              value::T
              next::Union{LinkedList{T}, Nothing}
          end

   julia> LinkedList("first", LinkedList("last", nothing))
   LinkedList{String}("first", LinkedList{String}("last", nothing))

   julia> LinkedList(1, LinkedList(2, nothing))
   LinkedList{Int64}(1, LinkedList{Int64}(2, nothing))
   ```
3. Instead of using `Union`s, the example code you posted uses abstract types and subtypes to describe the possibility of having either a node or the final nil element.  `<:` is the [subtyping operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#Abstract-Types-1).

Comment: In `Union{LinkedList{T}, Void}`, you should replace `Void` by `Nothing`